# Android activity keeps crashing on orientation change

Tags: android, landscape-portrait

I am experiencing a rather subtle and undetectable bug in one of my Android app's activities.  Under certain conditions, when I transition the activity from landscape to portrait, or vice-versa, the app crashes.  What is particularly difficult and annoying about this bug is that none of the breakpoints in the activity are being hit in debug mode when I do the transition.  In addition, logcat does not seem to be much help, and nothing shows up there either.

So I would be looking for some suggestions about what could cause a crash on orientation change.  I can post some code, but I obviously can't post everything, and I'm not sure how much help it would be to post a few fragments from the activity.

Comment: i faced similar issue before, related with onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() functions, kindly refer the following post:- https://android.jlelse.eu/handling-orientation-changes-in-android-7072958c442a

Comment: @nandal Do we need two entries in the manifest if an activity has both a portrait and landscape layout XML file?

Comment: No no, we don't need to have two entries in manifest

Comment: Then the link you gave won't help.  It suggest departing from the default behavior and suppressing the recreation of the activity.  Maybe this would work, but the Android documentation generally recommends against doing this.

Comment: no no, it shows different ways to handle this error, one of them is to use only one specific layout, but look at the following:- To save the state information override onSaveInstanceState() method and add key-value pairs to the Bundle object that is saved in the event that your activity is destroyed unexpectedly. This method gets called before onStop().
To recover your saved state from the Bundle override onRestoreInstanceState() method. This is called after onStart() and before onResume().

Comment: Check your activity's members. Maybe comment them out one by one (also commenting out the code that uses them) until it stops crashing. In most cases this happens if your code relies on some data stored in the variables

Comment: @DennisK I'm heading in this direction.  I will add log statements to each method to see where the problem might be.  But again, the breakpoints aren't hitting anywhere, so I don't expect to see much more.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what's happening with your app/logcat that it crashes without a crash dump. This is why I'm suggesting to remove code instead of adding more.

Comment: If nothing arises (very small chance, I know) but I would suggest using some AVD with differente API setups, maybe logcat show something new then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was on the verge of giving up, when something turned up in Logcat after one of the failed tests:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
    com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker.setIcon
   (com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor)' on a null object reference
```

I followed the stack trace to the point in the activity where the null pointer exception happened.  In fact, as many of you suggested in comments, there was some state which was not being restored properly.  The exact problem was happening in the initialization of a Google Map.

At first glance now, this question seems to be of the "why isn't this code working" type.  However, it is not, because both debugging and, most of the time, Logcat, failed to reveal what the problem was.

As a take home message, if you ever encounter bugs in your Android code, you should not rely on debugging alone, because it might not work.  Logcat seems to have come through here, but even it seemed to not be reproducible every time.

Answer (score 1):

The lifecycle of an `Activity` is such that on orientation change events like `onCreate()` and `onStop()` (for example) are not called. So, if you have created objects in `onCreate()` they might not be initialized (=`null`) when your `Activity` returns after being rotated. Check your code for objects that might be initialized in `onCreate()`.

Also you might want to add a few more `try..catch` with `Log.e` messages.

To be honest, if your app crashes, there should be an error logged in the logcat.

Comment: Actually, my understanding is that the default behavior for an activity is that it would be destroyed and recreated on orientation change.  This is why we save state in the bundle, to be used in `onCreate`.  But I agree with your comment about logcat.  Mystery why nothing shows up.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen :: yes, you can save the state in the `bundle` and restore  the `bundle` but you must do it actively. I do not know what views you are using or how you have defined your objects. But, it is still possible that some are not being initialized after rotation. To be honest, I limit most of my apps so that the orientation cannot be change--unless it is really necessary for a pleasant UX

Comment: Agree +1, and the only reason I am doing this is that leaving it in portrait mode everywhere would result in an ugly UI in landscape mode.